# Find maximum of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the maximum of a function.

$$ d = \frac{35}{3} + \frac{7}{3}\sin( \frac{2\pi}{365}t ) $$

I don't know if I applied the chain rule correctly.

$$ w = \frac{2\pi}{365}t $$

$$ w' = \frac{2\pi}{365} $$

$$ g = \sin(w) $$

$$ g' = \cos(w) $$

$$ f = \frac{35}{3} + \frac{7}{3}g $$

$$ f' = \frac{7}{3}g $$

$$ d' = \frac{7}{3}\sin( \frac{2\pi}{365}t ) \times \cos( \frac{2\pi}{365}t ) \times \frac{2\pi}{365} $$

I set it to $0$
$$ a\times b \times c = 0 $$

And it seems that I can't solve this because $x = 0$

$$ \arcsin(a) = \arcsin(0) \\
\frac{2\pi}{365}x = 0 \\
x = 0$$

Comment: Don't need to differentiate, the max of sin is $1$.

Comment: Largest value is $14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(s)\in [-1,1]$ for any $s$, we have

$$d=\frac{35}{3} + \frac{7}{3}\sin\Big( \frac{2\pi}{365}t \Big)\leq \frac{35}{3} + \frac{7}{3}=\frac{42}{3}=14$$

for every $t$. Now, you have to find $t$ such that $\sin\Big( \frac{2\pi}{365}t \Big)=1$. By periodicity of $\sin$ this is true whenever $$\frac{2\pi}{365}t = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \iff t = \frac{365}{2\pi}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \Big)=\frac{365}{4}+k365$$ with $k\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)

$$\dfrac{d(d)}{dt}=\dfrac73\cos\dfrac{2\pi t}{365}\cdot\dfrac{2\pi }{365}$$

For the extreme values of $d,\cos\dfrac{2\pi t}{365}=0\implies\dfrac{2\pi t}{365}=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}2$ where $n$ is any integer

Can you continue from here?